# iis6 domain name configuration

Tags: iis-6, windows-sbs-2003

I have a website with a domain such as `www.example.com` and also `example.com` on iis6. The problem is that `example.com` goes to the sbs 3003 server welcome screen. I want example.com to be the same as `www.example.com` but I'm not sure how I can configure this?

From other articles that I've read Ive done the following:

1. In iis6 right click on website and click properties
2. Click advanced and add host header value `example.com`

Answer (score 2):

You need to go into your bindings and make sure both domains added to the Site Bindings:

Here is an example:

http://www.bunkerhollow.com/blogs/matt/IIS6MultipleSites2.PNG

Comment: Right answer. Wrong picture. Those pictures are for IIS7, the OP stated IIS6.

Comment: that better? :D

Comment: Much..........:)

Comment: The problem is that I already have these settings but I'm still hitting the sbs server

Comment: It sounds like you are over writing it somewhere. This should be the only place you need to specify those settings. Try removing it everywhere else you have added it.